# ActionScript 3 - how to set empty display object variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, displayobject, nonetype

What I initially wanted to do is this:

```
if (myTargetName == 'a') {
    var myOtherTargetName:String = "b";
    var myOtherTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(myOtherTargetName);
}


if (myTargetName == 'c') {
    var myOtherTargetName:String = "d";
    var myOtherTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(myOtherTargetName);
}
```

as you can see, I get a 'Duplicate variable definition' error since im declaring the variables twice. My solution I thought would be to just declare those variables outside the if statements, and change the variable inside the statement, like so:

```
var myOtherTargetName:String = ""
var myOtherTarget:DisplayObject = None;
if (myTargetName == 'a') {
    myOtherTargetName = "b";
    myOtherTarget = getChildByName(myOtherTargetName);
}


if (myTargetName == 'c') {
    myOtherTargetName = "d";
    myOtherTarget = getChildByName(myOtherTargetName);
}
```

This gives an error saying "access of undefined property None". Now, I don't want to set

```
myOtherTarget:DisplayObject
```

to an actual existing display object which is on the stage just yet, I want to set it to an object on the stage inside the if statements. Is there a way to set

```
myOtherTarget:DisplayObject
```

to nothing?

Comment: Try this one: `var myOtherTarget:DisplayObject = null;` , or  simply `var myOtherTarget:DisplayObject;`

Comment: @Cherniv worked, thanks. you can put that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy, copy+paste it:

```
var myOtherTarget:DisplayObject = null;
```

or simply:

```
var myOtherTarget:DisplayObject;
```